# can i connect API with STORM or KAFKA

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, apache-storm

I'm making a project of auto stock trading system with deep-learning
I have stock market's API and want to connect with Hadoop clusters
can I connect API with KAFKA or STORM?

Answer (score 0):

Hope you want to connect like below:

API <- KAFKA <- HADOOP

If yes, then Kafka can be hooked up to hadoop and you can connect to Kafka from your API.
But to connect to Kafka, you need to go via Zookeeper. There is no reason to avoid zookeeper at any stage. You can connect without zookeeper as well but you will have to do some modification if it is your sandbox. Since you are supposed to run it in prod env, you can't skip zookeeper unless your organization has decided so.

Comment: and also I want make a flow -STORM-IMPALA can I do it with just ZOOKEEPER?

Comment: You can but you need some adapter. Flume could be your adapter without writing any code. Moreover, not sure why you want to use storm when spark is in trend now.

Comment: spark also great way. I just don't use Flume api-storm/spark it's what i wanted